# Call switch case into switch case

Tags: bash

I want to call switch case into switch case. But I get error.

```
### User prompts
read -p "Would you like to download all source codes and build them? \"(Y|N)\" " inPut
# Get user prompt not case sensitive
case $inPut in
# First case
"y"|"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code

    read -p "Would you like to start all servers? \"(Y|N)\" " inPutserver
    case $inPutserver in
    "y"|"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
    open_new_terminals_automatically $DIR "rails -s"

;;

# Second case
"n"|"N") echo 'Stopping script execution...'
exit
;;

esac
```

I get error when I run the script:

```
run.sh: line 589: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not terminated the inner `case` construct which should have been as below.

```
read -p "Would you like to start all servers? \"(Y|N)\" " inPutserver
case $inPutserver in
"y"|"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
open_new_terminals_automatically $DIR "rails -s"
;;
esac      # <------ Notice the termination here.
```

Make use of http://www.shellcheck.net and fix your trivial issues in the script from there.